# Multi tenancy with Schemas and RLS in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am new to Postgres/databases and am thinking of how to design a multi tenant application. I read some of the basic stuff such as schemas supported by Postgres and Row Level Security which is added since Postgres 9.5. So in my case a tenant can have many users. Two different tenants can have users with same name ( Kind of like a hierarchy).  So at the top level, I can have a schema for each tenant.  And then within each there is a RLS policy for users.  Can this be done in Postgres and is this a good option ? With RLS, I will need a role for each user. This will probably blow up since my understanding is that roles are global across schemas.

Or other thing I can think of is that I keep everything in same tables but have policies which honor the user as well as tenant columns in the table. Is this possible in Postgres ? For example, when I add a policy with current_users = "column_name" ,can I add  another condition where I add a check that the top level tenant name matches.  But where and how is this set, similar to SET ROLE  "user"

Bit confused about the right approach to use.

Comment: "*I will need a role for each user*" - you already have that. A user **is** a role (with the "login" privilege). But if you don't need cross-tenant queries, then I agree with Neil: use one database per tenant

Answer (score 2):

I would go with tenant per database. This is a little easier to backup (per tenant) and a little more secure by default. And a little easier to manage w pgAdmin.

You don't *need* a db user for each application user to use RLS, but it's probably a good idea.

Set `db_user_namespace=true` in `postgresql.conf` to allow per-db usernames. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/runtime-config-connection.html for caveats